# Question about composite mapping (matrices operations)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: V\rightarrow W$ and $U:W \rightarrow Z$ be linear mappings, and let $A= [U]^\gamma_\beta$ and $B=[T]^\beta_\alpha$, where $\alpha$={$v_1,v_2,...v_n$}, $\beta$= {$w_1,w_2,...,w_m$}, and $\gamma$={$z_1,z_2,...,z_p$} are ordered bases for V,W, and Z. Define the product AB of two matrices so that $AB$=$[UT]^\gamma_\alpha$. Consider $[UT]^\gamma_\alpha$. For 1 $\leqq$ j $\leqq n$, we have
>
> [image: >]

My Question is for U($\sum_{k=1}^m B_{kj} w_k$), since the matrix operation is row by column, B is a m by n matrix, $w_k$ has m elements, somehow I don't get this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $U$ is a linear operator and so $U(\sum_k B_{kj}w_k) = \sum_k B_{kj}U(w_k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\sum_k {B_{kj}w_k}$ is the defintion of matrix representation ,from which we could get the jth column of the matrix $B$. Map the jth vector in the basis for V and then express them by the ordered basis in W. The coefficents of the linear combination are the jth column of B.